# Working with UIScrollViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I've watched many Youtube videos on UIScrollView. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RV7vz4WSy7w&t=140s), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J22gHORk2I) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hIyn_UdFIc&t=414s). However nothing there is solving my issue.

Here I've a sample storyboard that I'm working with.

[image]

**What I require:**

1. The ViewController must be embedded in a Navigation Controller.
2. `BlueView` and `CyanView` will adjust its height accordingly to screen size based on aspect ratio.
3. `YellowView` will have a variable height as it contains a ContainerView with embedded `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. Meaning my users can switch between views to look at similar data, with different format. Its information is grabbed from server side. This means that if there is no content, it doesn't require any scrolling. If there are many rows of data to fetch, scrolling should work to display all my information.

**Problem faced**

1. If I do not set specific heights to each of my views, IB will complain about the need for constraints on height or Y position.
2. When I try specifying the height in IB (so as to avoid the complain), during runtime, I attempt to change the height of my `yellowView` and `myScrollView`, the scrolling doesn't happen at all.

Comment: I suggest to add it as a table view -or collection view if needed- instead of scroll view, I think that handling the colored views as cell is easier and more adaptive.

Comment: If you want to make that effects , what the most people will do is using `UITableVIew` is a main tableView, and each of `UITableViewCells` heights depends on its content.      Such as, `UITableViewCell` embedded a `UIView` or `UITableView`

Comment: @AhmadF To be more specific, I used UIViews because within that view, I can change to either `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` to view the data of different format.

Comment: @VictorJohn As per explain to AhmadF, I needed yellow because of its "switchable" views that allows me to view the same information but of different format. You can take a look at Instagram Profile Tab, something similar to that.

Comment: Or adding a constraint of height on `yellowView` when initialized. And connecting a height of property of  `yellowView` to your viewController. Then changing the height at any time.  Constraints can be a property too.

Comment: Well, you can also do this within a `UITableViewCell`...

Comment: @AhmadF Would that mean its not possible? I would still prefer adjusting my `UIScrollView` rather than `UITableViewCell` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `UIScrollView` add a container View. That will contain rest of your views. So the heirarchy becomes like this:

```
|---UIScrollView
       |----UIView
               |---Blue View
               |---Cyan View
               |---Yellow View
```

This container view will have a *leading*, *trailing* and *bottom* and *top* to the `UIScrollView`. Also add a *equal width* and *equal height* constraint to your `UIViewController`s main view. Give a priority of `250` to the *equal height* constraint. And then:

- To the *blue view*, add a *leading*, *trailing* and *top* constraint to its *superView* and add the *aspect ratio* constraint. Tinker with the values till you see a `UIView` which looks nice to you.
- To the *cyan view*, add a *leading* and *trailing* to its *superView* and add a *top spacing* to the *blue view*. Add the same *aspect ratio* as the *blue view*.
- Now for your *yellow view*, add a *top* to the *cyan view*, and *leading*, *trailing* and *bottom* spacing to its *superView*.

Now your `UITableView` will have a *leading*, *trailing*, *bottom* and *top* to the container view or just directly use a `UITableView`.

**If** you wish to embed a `UITableView` inside the yellow view or just use a `UITableView` directly and expect the main `UIScrollView` to be scrollable, you will have to manually get a height constraint outlet for your `UITableView` and update it accordingly depending on the number of rows of the `UITableView` and height of each row so that the `yellow view` can increase its height based on the height of the embedded `UITableView` and hence update the content view accordingly which will in turn update the total content size of the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Your answer seems legit. I will give it a try and let you know the result. By the way, the child view of `UIScrollView` shouldn't be Container View right? It should be just a `UIView`?

Comment: Yep, its a normal `UIView`! Sorry for the confusion i'm just used to calling it a container view!

Comment: I tried to place the `BlueView`, `CyanView`, `YellowView` it couldn't work. However I tried to place it directly under the `ScrollView` it worked! Adding IBOutlet for the height of `YellowView` was the key to this whole thing! Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work by adding all 3 inside a `UIView`? Thats surprising! As long as your problem is solved!